# How to build flutter iOS app without AppStore

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, app-store

I made an app for me and my friends and I don't intend on publishing it on the app store, it's easy to build the apk file for android and send it to them but some have iPhones. Is it possible to build the IPA without an apple dev account, macOS and all those certificates?

I would install it with cydia impactor and renting a mac server to do the build is no problem.I read the post on flutter.dev but it's overwhelming for what I want to do.

Comment: you will need only apple developer account.. with help of [code magic](https://codemagic.io/)

Comment: You can also use the python CLI tool [appollo](https://github.com/Appollo-CLI/Appollo) to build your IPA without a Mac. You will need an Apple Developer account though. I feel like Omatt's solution is better suited for your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to create an unsigned iOS .ipa without code signing or Apple Developer account.

1. Run the Flutter app first to an iOS simulator to generate iOS build on **/build/ios**.
2. Create a folder anywhere you like with
   the name `Payload` - note that this is case sensitive.
3. Navigate
   to **/build/ios/iphonesimulator** and copy Runner.app to the
   `Payload` folder you've created.
4. Compress the `Payload` folder with
   default .zip format
5. Rename **Payload.zip** to **Payload.ipa**

Comment: I didn't know this solution, pretty neat ! I personally use [Appollo](https://github.com/Appollo-CLI/Appollo) to have access to MacOS build machines but it requires a Developer Account.